# May I use comma as decimal separator on SQLite?

Tags: sqlite

I imported TSV files using Firefox SQLite Manager but the decimal separator is comma and math functions are ignoring the decimal part of the value. Could you help me?

Thank you

Comment: Do a search & replace the comma for a decimal before you load the data into SQLite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used Firefox SQLite but I have used SQLiteman and with this GUI was a problem work with comma as decimal mark (if your database is light perhaps you can 'replace' those commas using an spreadsheet or something like that...). In my case, as my database was really large, the solution was use the raw SQLite shell: I imported perfectly a csv file (separated by ;) with commas as decimal mark. Additionally, the importing process was faster. Cheers.